# IPython Installation with Spark 2.2 on CDH 5.12

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ipython, lts

I have a cluster with Spark 2.2 on CDH 5.12 with RHEL and I am trying to set up IPython to use with pyspark2. I have installed IPython 5.x LTS (long term support) but I am not able to get it to work.

So far

```
yum -y update
yum install epel-release
yum -y install python-pip
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
yum install python-devel

pip install IPython==5.0 --user
```

But I am unable to get it to work. Anyone with an idea of what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

pyspark launch script looks for,

```
# Determine the Python executable to use for the driver:
if [[ -n "$IPYTHON_OPTS" || "$IPYTHON" == "1" ]]; then
  # If IPython options are specified, assume user wants to run IPython
  # (for backwards-compatibility)
  PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="$PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS $IPYTHON_OPTS"
  PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="ipython"
elif [[ -z "$PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON" ]]; then
  PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="${PYSPARK_PYTHON:-"$DEFAULT_PYTHON"}"
fi
```

set below variables in your `~/.bashrc`

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/path_to_downloaded_spark/spark-1.6.0/bin"
echo "export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython"
echo "export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Comment: It is probably really close, I am still getting this error: env: ipython: No such file or directory